# How do I get the content of excuting commend with Su?

Tags: android, robotium, android-uiautomator

When I excuted a commend, such as `am start -W -n com.xxx.xxx/.xxActivity`
I can see the content.
`Starting: Intent { cmp=com.xxx.xxx/.xxActivity }
Status: ok
Activity: com.xxx.xxx/.xxActivity
ThisTime: 52
TotalTime: 71
Complete`

But when I excuted a commend with su ,such as `su -c "am start -W -n com.xxx.xxx/.xxActivity"`
there is nothing to output, how can I get the output with su?

Comment: why you use su if you get output without using su ?

Comment: because some activities need su to start or get the Exception (java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial:)

Answer (score 0):

The standard Android `su` works as expected if run properly:

```
 $ su 0 am start -W -n com.android.settings/.Settings
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings }
Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
Status: ok
Activity: com.android.settings/.Settings
ThisTime: 0
TotalTime: 0
Complete
```

Here's an excerpt from the [`su.c`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/su/su.c) code:

```
/*
 * SU can be given a specific command to exec. UID _must_ be
 * specified for this (ie argc => 3).
 *
 * Usage:
 *   su 1000
 *   su 1000 ls -l
 *  or
 *   su [uid[,gid[,group1]...] [cmd]]
 *  E.g.
 *  su 1000,shell,net_bw_acct,net_bw_stats id
 * will return
 *  uid=1000(system) gid=2000(shell) groups=3006(net_bw_stats),3007(net_bw_acct)
 */
```